# Knockout not rendering client side select box until refresh (Breeze.js)

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, breeze

I am undoubtedly missing something obvious here. This is the first front end application I have created.

I'd like to have a client side select box which when an option is chosen, a separate property on the entity will be updated. Meaning when a select box is changed, a function is called which will then update the other property appropriately. The issue I am having is that when an entity is created on the client side, the select box does not render.

In pictures:

[Step One](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S5tba.png): The page is loaded. The entity exists with no children:

[Step Two](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y4k9C.png): Add Child is clicked, and a child entity is created. As you can see the select box has no options. Using the Chrome Knockout plugin I am able to see that the property which contains the options which are supposed to be rendered is correct.

[Step Three](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZntWO.png): I click save and then refresh the page. The select box renders correctly but importantly the value which populates this select box is the same as step two (verified via knockout chrome plugin).

HTML:

```
<section data-bind="with: parent">
  <div data-bind="foreach: children">
    <select name="propertyOne" 
      data-bind="options: propertyOneOptions, value: propertyOne, optionsText: 'description', optionsCaption: 'Select a Property'">
    </select>
    <br />
  </div>
  <button data-bind="click: $root.addChild">Add Child</button>
</section>
<button data-bind="click: save">Save</button>
```

View Model:

As you can see, in both the initVm method and in the addChild method I am populating child.propertyOneOptions.

```
app.viewModel = (function (logger, dataservice) {

  var parent = ko.observable(null);
  var propertyOneValues = ko.observableArray([]);

  var vm = {
    addChild: addChild,
    parent: parent,
    save: save,
  };

  initVm();

  return vm;

  function initVm() {
    propertyOneValues.push({
      key: 'key 1',
      description: 'value 1'
    });
    propertyOneValues.push({
      key: 'key 2',
      description: 'value 2'
    });
    dataservice.getAllParents()
      .then(function (data) {
        console.log('Number of parents = ' + data.results.length);
        if (data.results.length > 0) {
          parent(data.results[0]);
        } else {
          parent(dataservice.createParent());
          dataservice.saveChanges().fail(queryFailed);
        }
        ko.utils.arrayForEach(parent().children(), function (child) {
          console.log('Populating Child ' + child.propertyOneOptions().length);
          ko.utils.arrayForEach(propertyOneValues(), function (value) {
            child.propertyOneOptions.push(value);
          });
          console.log('Populated Child ' + child.propertyOneOptions().length);
        });
      }).fail(queryFailed);
  }
  function queryFailed(error) {
    console.log('Query failed: ' + error.message);
  }
  function save() {
    dataservice.saveChanges().fail(queryFailed);
  }
  function addChild() {
    var child = dataservice.createChild(parent);
    console.log('Creating Child ' + child.propertyOneOptions().length);
    ko.utils.arrayForEach(propertyOneValues(), function (value) {
      child.propertyOneOptions.push(value);
    });
    console.log('Populated Child ' + child.propertyOneOptions().length);
  }
})(app.logger, app.dataservice);

// Bind viewModel to view in index.html
ko.applyBindings(app.viewModel);
```

Child Initializer:

propertyOne and propertyOneOptions are creating a breeze entity initializer:

```
function childInitializer(child) {
  child.propertyOne = ko.observable();
  child.propertyOneOptions = ko.observableArray();
}
```

Data Model:

```
public class Parent
{
  public Parent()
  {
    Children = new List<Child>();
  }
  [Key]
  public int Id { get; set; }

  public String OtherProperty { get; set; }

  public IList<Child> Children { get; set; }

}
public class Child
{
  [Key]
  public int Id { get; set; }

  public int ParentId { get; set; }

  [ForeignKey("ParentId")]
  public Parent Parent { get; set; }
}
```

**Update 1**

After reading [this](http://www.knockmeout.net/2012/04/knockoutjs-performance-gotcha.html) on performance I added:

```
parent().children.valueHasMutated();
```

to the end of addChild method and thing have improved, that is a child select box does render, but there is a phantom child below the correct child: [Updated Step Two](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wQd6C.png)

Comment: I added debug statements to the options.init and options.update ko bindings as expected when I hit refresh they are called correctly but when I click add, they are not.

Comment: What does `dataservice.createChild(parent)` look like? Does it add the created child to the parent list?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should never have to call valueHasMutated.  I have never ran into a circumstance where it was actually needed.  The problem is most likely that you haven't loaded up all of the properties before you notify Knockout of the added entity, and when it tries to bind the binding is breaking.

```
function addChild() {
    // Don't pass a parent into createChild yet
    var child = dataservice.createChild();
    // After the entity is created, then assign the parent property
    child().parent(parent());
    console.log('Creating Child ' + child.propertyOneOptions().length);
    ko.utils.arrayForEach(propertyOneValues(), function (value) {
      child.propertyOneOptions.push(value);
    });
    console.log('Populated Child ' + child.propertyOneOptions().length);
  }
```

This always works for me.